# Session in wordpress not quite working

Tags: php, html, wordpress, session

I want to use the SESSION function of PHP on my word press blog. I added a `session_start()` to my wp-config.php file and I commented the `wp_unregister_globals();` out.

With `session_id();` I am able to get an ID shown but in this source code, nothing works, I can't even display the session_id()

```
    <div class="anzahl_pakete">
        Spendenpakete im Parkkorb:[php] echo session_id();
$anzahl = 0;
$keys = array_keys($_SESSION);
for($i=0;$i<count($keys);$i++)
{
if($_SESSION[$keys[$i]] != 0)
{$anzahl++;}
}
echo $anzahl;[/php]
```

Comment: I think you have to write `session_start()` in header.php file

Comment: No, that changed nothing :(

Comment: I think I am going for an simple iFrame...

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need to use a session?  What about the transients or options apis built into WordPress?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
// On your plugin or themes functions.php

function register_session(){
    if( !session_id())
        session_start();
}

add_action('init','register_session');
// On you code

$_SESSION['key'] = $abc;
// On your ajax file

if( !session_id())
session_start();

$abc = $_SESSION['key'];
```